# Почему скопированная ссылка сайта отличается от того, что мы видим в адресной строке?

Tags: python

Задача такова: реализовать поиск на сайте https://znanija.com/ исходя из сообщения пользователя и выдавать ему ссылку на выданные результаты.
Пример:
Пользователь вводит

> первый закон термодинамики

Идём на сайт, заходим в поиск, вводим, получаем, что в нашей адресной строке написано

> znanija.com/app/ask?entry=hero&q=первый+закон+термодинамики

Ожидаемо, что нужно парсить сообщение и преобразовывать их в ссылку подобного вида, однако, если перейти по этой ссылке, то нам выдаёт ошибку. Также, если скопировать эту ссылку, то выходит

> https://znanija.com/app/ask?entry=hero&q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8

Что является рабочей ссылкой. Сам вопрос: есть ли простой метод создания подобных рабочих ссылок, исходя из сообщений пользователя? При этом это должна быть автоматизированная работа на языке Python.

Comment: Просто экранированы все не-ASCII символы

Comment: если перейти по этой ссылке, то нам выдаёт ошибку© - значит кто-то ленивая задница, ровно сидящая на своём месте.
А чтобы ссылка копировалась в человеческом виде - добавь пробел в конце, потом копируй.
А тут ответ на твой вопрос: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+encode+URL

Comment: @qwabra Спасибо! Я попросту не знал, что именно гуглить.

Comment: @user321409, пожалуйста. свои ответы тоже можно и нужно принимать как ответ (ставить галочку). правда я бы добавил ссылку на какие-либо доки. например для JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: @qwabra дополнил ответ. Галочку не поставил потому, что возможно принять только через два дня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение для Python:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

reply = 'https://znanija.com/app/ask?entry=hero&q=' + format(quote(quest)))
```

Где quest это переменная типа str с содержанием запроса пользователя.

Похожий метод для JavaScript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI